# Airflow CeleryKubernetesExecutor ImagePullBackOff - Image not created

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, minikube, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-k8s

I'm trying to execute a DAG using Kubernetes Executor but the pod does not start and fails with

`ImagePullBackOff`

```
stream logs failed container "base" in pod "dag-3-dry-run-demo-as2pjum1" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image for de │ry-run-demo-86tn0dxg ( │
│ fault/dag-3-dry-run-demo-as2pjum1 (base)
```

[image]

DAG code

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


def print_hello():
    print("Hello world from first Airflow DAG!")


dag = DAG(
    "dag_2",
    description="Hello World DAG",
    schedule_interval="0 12 * * *",
    start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20),
    catchup=False,
)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(
    task_id="hello_k8s", python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag, queue="kubernetes"
)

hello_operator
```

Used [this](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/guides/quickstart.md) helm to install AirFlow.

Am I missing some config here?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ImagePullBackOff` error](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#imagepullbackoff) you see in Kubernetes usually indicates that Kubernetes is unable to fetch the container image specified.

As mentioned in "[Kubernetes: ImagePullBackOff!](https://blog.ediri.io/kubernetes-imagepullbackoff)" from [Engin Diri](https://github.com/dirien), and "[Troubleshooting Kubernetes ImagePullBackOff](https://www.airplane.dev/blog/kubernetes-imagepullbackoff)", you need to review the possible causes for this error message:

- Make sure the image name and tag are correct. Verify if the image exists in the container registry you are using.
- If the image is in a private registry, ensure that Kubernetes has the necessary credentials to access it. You may need to create a Kubernetes Secret with the registry credentials and reference it in your Airflow configuration.
- Check if there are any network policies or connectivity issues that might be preventing Kubernetes from accessing the container registry.
- Check the status of the container registry to ensure it's functioning properly.
- Verify your Airflow configuration, especially the settings related to Kubernetes Executor and the container image. Check if there are any overrides in the [Helm chart](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/guides/quickstart.md) values that might be affecting the image pulling process.
- Make sure the [`imagePullPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy) is set to a value that allows Kubernetes to pull the image. The common values are `Always`, `IfNotPresent`, and `Never`.